# Переписать в новую строку слова, в которых гласные буквы чередуются с согласными

Tags: c#, .net

Код готов, но выглядит, мягко говоря, страшно. Есть ли методы, которыми можно оформить проверку более элегантно? Эта длиннющая строка реально выглядит пугающе...

```
static void Alternation(string text)
    {
        string result = " Result:  ";
        //int i1 = 0, i2 = 0;
        
        string[] S = text.Split(' ');

        for (int i1 = 0; i1 <= S.Length - 1; i1++)
        {
            bool Check = false;
            if (S[i1] != S[S.Length - 1])
                for (int i2 = 0; i2 <= S[i1].Length - 2; i2++)
                    if (((S[i1][i2] == 'а' | S[i1][i2] == 'е' | S[i1][i2] == 'и' | S[i1][i2] == 'о' | S[i1][i2] == 'у' | S[i1][i2] == 'А' | S[i1][i2] == 'Е' | S[i1][i2] == 'И' | S[i1][i2] == 'О' | S[i1][i2] == 'У') & (S[i1][i2 + 1] == 'б' | S[i1][i2 + 1] == 'в' | S[i1][i2 + 1] == 'г' | S[i1][i2 + 1] == 'д' | S[i1][i2 + 1] == 'ж' | S[i1][i2 + 1] == 'з' | S[i1][i2 + 1] == 'й' | S[i1][i2 + 1] == 'к' | S[i1][i2 + 1] == 'л' | S[i1][i2 + 1] == 'м' | S[i1][i2 + 1] == 'н' | S[i1][i2 + 1] == 'п' | S[i1][i2 + 1] == 'р' | S[i1][i2 + 1] == 'с' | S[i1][i2 + 1] == 'т' | S[i1][i2 + 1] == 'ф' | S[i1][i2 + 1] == 'х' | S[i1][i2 + 1] == 'ц' | S[i1][i2 + 1] == 'ч' | S[i1][i2 + 1] == 'ш' | S[i1][i2 + 1] == 'щ' | S[i1][i2 + 1] == 'Б' | S[i1][i2 + 1] == 'В' | S[i1][i2 + 1] == 'Г' | S[i1][i2 + 1] == 'Д' | S[i1][i2 + 1] == 'Ж' | S[i1][i2 + 1] == 'З' | S[i1][i2 + 1] == 'Й' | S[i1][i2 + 1] == 'К' | S[i1][i2 + 1] == 'Л' | S[i1][i2 + 1] == 'М' | S[i1][i2 + 1] == 'Н' | S[i1][i2 + 1] == 'П' | S[i1][i2 + 1] == 'Р' | S[i1][i2 + 1] == 'С' | S[i1][i2 + 1] == 'Т' | S[i1][i2 + 1] == 'Ф' | S[i1][i2 + 1] == 'Х' | S[i1][i2 + 1] == 'Ц' | S[i1][i2 + 1] == 'Ч' | S[i1][i2 + 1] == 'Ш' | S[i1][i2 + 1] == 'Щ')) | ((S[i1][i2] == 'б' | S[i1][i2] == 'в' | S[i1][i2] == 'г' | S[i1][i2] == 'д' | S[i1][i2] == 'ж' | S[i1][i2] == 'з' | S[i1][i2] == 'й' | S[i1][i2] == 'к' | S[i1][i2] == 'л' | S[i1][i2] == 'м' | S[i1][i2] == 'н' | S[i1][i2] == 'п' | S[i1][i2] == 'р' | S[i1][i2] == 'с' | S[i1][i2] == 'т' | S[i1][i2] == 'ф' | S[i1][i2] == 'х' | S[i1][i2] == 'ц' | S[i1][i2] == 'ч' | S[i1][i2] == 'ш' | S[i1][i2] == 'щ' | S[i1][i2] == 'Б' | S[i1][i2] == 'В' | S[i1][i2] == 'Г' | S[i1][i2] == 'Д' | S[i1][i2] == 'Ж' | S[i1][i2] == 'З' | S[i1][i2] == 'Й' | S[i1][i2] == 'К' | S[i1][i2] == 'Л' | S[i1][i2] == 'М' | S[i1][i2] == 'Н' | S[i1][i2] == 'П' | S[i1][i2] == 'Р' | S[i1][i2] == 'С' | S[i1][i2] == 'Т' | S[i1][i2] == 'Ф' | S[i1][i2] == 'Х' | S[i1][i2] == 'Ц' | S[i1][i2] == 'Ч' | S[i1][i2] == 'Ш' | S[i1][i2] == 'Щ') & (S[i1][i2 + 1] == 'а' | S[i1][i2 + 1] == 'е' | S[i1][i2 + 1] == 'и' | S[i1][i2 + 1] == 'о' | S[i1][i2 + 1] == 'у' | S[i1][i2 + 1] == 'А' | S[i1][i2 + 1] == 'Е' | S[i1][i2 + 1] == 'И' | S[i1][i2 + 1] == 'О' | S[i1][i2 + 1] == 'У')))
                        Check = true;
                    else { Check = false; break; }

            if (Check == true) result = result + ' ' + S[i1];
        }

        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
```

Comment: Откройте для себя [`HashSet`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1?view=net-5.0)

Comment: @tym32167 спасибо, конечно, за подсказку, но почитав про это в доксах, пока что не понял как это сделать. И улучшит ли это читаемость? P.S. возможно, я не совсем правильно понял как именно это использовать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы не стал делить строку на подстроки-слова, а выделял бы подстроки только когда необходимо. Также используйте подходяшие структуры данных типа HashSet когда вам надо узнать, входит ли буква в какое то множество. Также имейте ввиду, что конкатенация строк - операция дорогая.

Пример

```
static void Alternation(string text)
{
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    result.Append( " Result:  ");
    
    HashSet<char> glasnye = new HashSet<char>("аеиоу");
    HashSet<char> soglasye = new HashSet<char>("бвгджзйклмнпрстфхцчшщ");
    
    int current = 0; 
    
    while(current < text.Length)
    {
        while(current < text.Length && text[current] == ' ') current++;
        
        var wordStart = current;
        var check = true;
        int glasCount = 0; 
        int soglCount = 0;

        while (current < text.Length && text[current] != ' ')
        {
            if (glasnye.Contains(char.ToLower(text[current]))) glasCount++;
            if (soglasye.Contains(char.ToLower(text[current]))) soglCount++;                    
            current++;
            if(Math.Abs(glasCount - soglCount) >= 2) check = false;
        }
        
        if (check && wordStart < current) {
            result.Append(" ");
            result.Append(text.Substring(wordStart, current - wordStart));
        }
        
    }

    Console.WriteLine(result.ToString());
}
```

Проверка

```
Alternation("   фафафа афафаф ааа ффф  ффф аф");
Alternation("   фафафа афафаф ааа ффф  ффф аф ");
```

Результат

```
Result:   фафафа афафаф аф
Result:   фафафа афафаф аф
```